# Printing a table of values

Tags: java

I have to print a table of values which consists of  7 rows and 6 columns. Please run the programs on your computer so that you can see what it outputs. How would you fix the code so all the values will fit neatly into the table?

```
public class Catapult {
    Catapult() {

    }

    public double[][] calcTrajectory(int ROWS, int COLS, int[] MPH, int[] degrees, double[][] trajectories) {
        for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
                trajectories[row][col] = Math.pow(MPH[row], 2) * Math.sin(2 * degrees[col]) / 9.8;
            }

        }
        return trajectories;
    }

    public static void printScores(double[][] trajectories, int ROWS, int COLS, int[] MPH) {
        System.out.println("                    Projectile Distance (feet)");
        System.out.println("   MPH      25 deg      30 deg      35 deg      35 deg      40 deg      45 deg");
        System.out.println("=====================================================================");

        for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
            System.out.printf("%5d", MPH[row]);
            for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
                System.out.printf("%13.2f", trajectories[row][col]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

---

```
public class CatapultTester
{
    static final int ROWS = 7;
    static final int COLS = 6;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Catapult object = new Catapult();
        int degrees[] = { 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50 };
        int MPH [] = { 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50};
        double[][] trajectories = new double[ROWS][COLS];
        trajectories = object.calcTrajectory(ROWS, COLS, MPH, degrees, trajectories);
        object.printScores(trajectories, ROWS, COLS, MPH);
    }
}
```

this is the output:

```
                   Projectile Distance (feet)
     MPH      25 deg      30 deg      35 deg      35 deg      40 deg      45 deg
 =============================================================================
     20
     25
     30
     35
     40
     45
     50
            -10.71       -12.44        31.59       -40.57        36.49       -20.67
            -16.73       -19.44        49.36       -63.39        57.02       -32.29
            -24.10       -27.99        71.07       -91.28        82.10       -46.50
            -32.80       -38.10        96.74      -124.24       111.75       -63.30
            -42.84       -49.76       126.35      -162.27       145.96       -82.67
            -54.22       -62.98       159.91      -205.37       184.73      -104.63
            -66.93       -77.76       197.42      -253.54       228.06      -129.17
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample output?  You could also use String builder to add each row in a specified format ending in a newline character, so you would guarantee the format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this :

```
for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
    System.out.printf("%5d\n", MPH[row]);
}
for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
        System.out.printf("%13.2f", trajectories[row][col]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

to this :

```
for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
    System.out.printf("%5d", MPH[row]);
    for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
        System.out.printf("%13.2f", trajectories[row][col]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

here is the output:

```
                    Projectile Distance (feet)
   MPH      25 deg      30 deg      35 deg      35 deg      40 deg      45 deg
=====================================================================
   20       -10.71       -12.44        31.59       -40.57        36.49       -20.67
   25       -16.73       -19.44        49.36       -63.39        57.02       -32.29
   30       -24.10       -27.99        71.07       -91.28        82.10       -46.50
   35       -32.80       -38.10        96.74      -124.24       111.75       -63.30
   40       -42.84       -49.76       126.35      -162.27       145.96       -82.67
   45       -54.22       -62.98       159.91      -205.37       184.73      -104.63
   50       -66.93       -77.76       197.42      -253.54       228.06      -129.17
```

your problem is from your `\n` at `System.out.printf("%5d\n", MPH[row]);`

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void printScores(double[][] trajectories, int ROWS, int COLS, int[] MPH){
   System.out.println("                    Projectile Distance (feet)");
   System.out.println("   MPH      25 deg      30 deg      35 deg      35 deg      40 deg          45 deg");
   System.out.println("=============================================================================="); 


   for(int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++){
       System.out.printf("%5d", MPH[row]);
       for(int col = 0; col < COLS; col++){
          System.out.printf("%13.2f", trajectories[row][col]);
       }
       System.out.println();
   }  
}
```

Out put

```
    MPH      25 deg      30 deg      35 deg      35 deg      40 deg      45 deg
==============================================================================
20       -10.71       -12.44        31.59       -40.57        36.49       -20.67
25       -16.73       -19.44        49.36       -63.39        57.02       -32.29
30       -24.10       -27.99        71.07       -91.28        82.10       -46.50
35       -32.80       -38.10        96.74      -124.24       111.75       -63.30
40       -42.84       -49.76       126.35      -162.27       145.96       -82.67
45       -54.22       -62.98       159.91      -205.37       184.73      -104.63
50       -66.93       -77.76       197.42      -253.54       228.06      -129.17
```